# store the values from command into an array bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, svn, unix

```
svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible http://svn.test.com/INT_1.0.0/ http://svn.test.com/DEV/  | cut -d"r" -f2 | cut -d" " -f1

6097
6099
```

when i put this in a script, i get only last value but not all:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

 src_url="http://svn.test.com/INT_1.0.0/"
 target_url="http://svn.test.com/DEV/"

 eligible_revs=(`svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible  $src_url $target_url | cut -d"r" -f2 | cut -d" " -f1`)

 echo ${eligible_revs[@]}

output:
6099
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Cygwin the line endings can mess it up

```
$ foo=(`printf 'bar\r\nbaz'`)

$ echo ${foo[*]}
 baz
```

Comment: How to get both the values or all values of command output in an array  - 6097,6099 ?

Comment: @jaav: Try adding `\r` to the list of field separators: `IFS+=$'\r'` before you set `eligible_revs`