# How to store values in array using batch script

Tags: batch-file

Is this possible to store list of packages in array using batch script.

```
SET array=(adb shell pm list packaages -3)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047376/store-the-values-from-command-into-an-array-bash

Comment: I changed the tag, but did you mean in a Windows batch file, as indicated by the title and the text in the question, or a `bash` script?

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_array.php

Comment: thnks...but still I am facing problem in editing string like...package:com:xyz..if i only want com:xyz...

Answer (score 2):

Although  I don't know bash, this is the way to store a list of *anything* in  a variable in Batch:

```
set Array=adb shell pm list packages -3
for %%v in (%Array%) do echo %%v
```

To group several words in the same element, enclose  they in quotes:

```
set Array=adb "shell pm" "list packages -3"
```

In this case you may use this form in order to eliminate the quotes:

```
for %%v in (%Array%) do echo %%~v
```

Comment: I show you how to _iterate_ on the values. The `echo` command just show each iterated value, so you must change it by the command you want to execute. I don't know what is the command you want to execute (I don't know bash, remember?  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
array=$(adb shell pm list packages -3)
```

Comment: Please avoid backticks... these were in use in the middle age. In the 21st century we use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: I am getting error like array is not defined as internal or external command in batch file.

Comment: Is `adb` in your `PATH`?

Comment: Can anyone convert this shell script in batch script

Array=($(./adb shell pm list packages -3))

For var in “${array[@]}”

Do

Pkg=${var#p*:}

Pkg=’echo –n ${pkg} | tr –d “\r”

./adb uninstall ${pkg}

Done